# Pushing A View Controller Crashes The App

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

Here's the scenario: I am using MWPhotoBrowser. I can push it fine once. The second time I try to push it the app crashes with nothing helpful. This is an ARC project, and this exact same code works fine in previous versions of the app. I am dumbfounded.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    if(browser == nil)
    {
        browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    }

    // Set options
    browser.displayActionButton = YES; // Show action button to allow sharing, copying, etc (defaults to YES)
    browser.displayNavArrows = YES; // Whether to display left and right nav arrows on toolbar (defaults to NO)
    browser.zoomPhotosToFill = NO; // Images that almost fill the screen will be initially zoomed to fill (defaults to YES)
    [browser setCurrentPhotoIndex:indexPath.row]; // Example: allows second image to be presented first
    //browser.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; // iOS 5 & 6 only: Decide if you want the photo browser full screen, i.e. whether the status bar is affected (defaults to YES)
    // Present
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
}
```

Tap a cell once, MWPhotoBrowser opens fine. Go back, tap a cell again, the app crashes just with the debugger but no call stack or error reason:

```
(lldb):
```

browser is a strong member variable. It isn't being deallocated prematurely. I can also guarantee it is crashing exactly on the last line of the method.

Can someone please enlighten me on this? I'd solve it if the app at least gave me a reason for the crash and not just throw the debugger on my face.

Comment: Where does it crash? What's the error? See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 if needed.

Comment: You have to type commands into the debugger. [more info](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) I'd start with `bt` for the backtrace.

Comment: @rmaddy: Like I said in the question description it crashed in the last line of the method, and also like I described it's not giving me a reason for the crash, just giving me the debugger.

Comment: Is it possible that `browser` isn't `nil` but points to a deallocated instance of `MWPhotoBrowser`?

Comment: @rmaddy looks like you were right. I got rid of the nil check and it seems to be working fine now... Maybe I should just go back to MRC...

Comment: How is `browser` declared?

Comment: It's simply an instance variable. `MWPhotoBrowser *browser;`, which I believe should be a strong variable by default. I am not a huge fan of my fix but it seems to be working. I may write my own answer once I have something more concrete.

Comment: If you log browser in the line above the if statement, what does it give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used MWPhotoBrowser extensively and ran across the same problem once. The way I solved it was by checking the MWPhoto objects to see if they actually had been set properly. I realised that I had not created some of them, hence the crash. I would check the place where you store your MWPhotos and make sure they are all set. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you could offer more of your code I could point you where the problem lies!

Comment: Heya Gabriel. If you check my code you wills see that I have a check to see if the photo browser is nil. Removing the check seems to solve the problem, though I'd think that's bound to cause memory leaks.